# How to call a React query useMutation only on a btn click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I have a custom `useMutation` hook, I will like to use this mutation only on btn click. What I'm seeing is that the mutation runs as soon as I mount my component and then on btn click. I will like for it to happen **only** on btn click.

This my custom useMutation hook:

```
export const constructOmgevingscheckPostRequest = (coordinates: string) => {
  console.log(
    'coordinates inside constructOmgevingscheckPostRequest',
    coordinates,
  );
  return {
    verzoekAard: 'ARC',
    geometrie: coordinates,
  };
};

export async function getOmgevingscheckData(coordinates: string) {
  console.log('coordinates inside getOmgevingscheckResult', coordinates);

  const { data: response } = await omgevingscheckApi.post(
    '/rs/v1/omgevingscheck',
    constructOmgevingscheckPostRequest(coordinates),
  );
  return response;
}

export function useOmgevingscheckMutation(coordinates: any) {
  return useMutation(['omgevingscheck', { coordinates }], () =>
    getOmgevingscheckData(coordinates),
  );
}
```

In my component I'm using it like so:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
// import { useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import { type IOmgevingscheckThema } from '../../types/IOmgevingscheckData';
import { Loading } from '@/components/Loading';
import { ErrorAlert } from '@/features/error/components';
import { useOmgevingscheckMutation } from '@/api';
import { usePolygonWktString } from '../../context/PolygonContext';

export function DesktopLayout() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState<number>(0);
  const { t } = useTranslation('app');

  const polygonWktString = usePolygonWktString();

  const useMutation = useOmgevingscheckMutation(
    polygonWktString?.polygonWktString,
  );

  const handleOmgevingscheckUitvoeren = () => {
    console.log(
      'polygonWktString from store',
      polygonWktString?.polygonWktString,
    );
    useMutation.mutate();
    setStep(step + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (useMutation.isSuccess) {
      // console.log('data', useMutation.data);
    }
  }, [useMutation.isSuccess, useMutation.isError]);

  // if (useMutation.isLoading) {
  //   console.log('loading');
  // }

  // if (useMutation.isError) {
  //   console.log('error');
  // }

  // console.log('useMutation.error', useMutation.error);
  // console.log('step', step);

  return (
    <>
      {useMutation.isLoading && (
        // Loading Component
      )}

      {useMutation.isError ? (
        // Error Component
      ) : null}

      {step === 0 && (
        <DesktopStepOne
          omgevingscheckUitvoeren={handleOmgevingscheckUitvoeren}
          isDisabled={polygonWktString?.polygonWktString ? false : true}
        />
      )}

      {step === 1 && useMutation.isSuccess && (
        // Component showing all of the data from the useMutation.data
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

It sort of works, but the problems/doubts/questions I'm having:

1. The `const useMutation = useOmgevingscheckMutation( polygonWktString?.polygonWktString);` runs when I first load the component, but I want it to run
   a. when I click the button && there's data to run the `post.request` it should not run if it's `data: null| undefined`(maybe throw an Error?)
2. I don't know if I'm handling `isLoading, isError, isSuccess` states from the `useMutation` on my component ?

Summary: how to handle a `useMutation` on only on btn Click?

Comment: I don't really understand, the mutation is your code is only run on click, `getOmgevingscheckData` is only called when `useMutation.mutate()` is called which is inside a click handler, presumably. Or are you calling `handleOmgevingscheckUitvoeren` on mount?

Comment: Your mutation function should be triggered only when .mutate() is called.  In your component `mutate()` is called in handleOmgevingscheckUitvoeren. This would mean that this function is evoked immediately instead of on click. Please provide the code for `DesktopStepOne`. I don't see an issue with the code you have provided. Your mutation function seems correct.